# Django Admin search field on foreignkey doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am building a django project and try to get a search bar on a "main" field which is called "regnr" (see models & admin modules below) but I get ani contains error when I search. I have tried search_fields = [foreignkey__name] and also [name_id] and also. [name] but nothing seems to work...

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Fordonsregister(models.Model):
    regnr = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    namn = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='070-000 00 00', null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    kund_sedan = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    kund_points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.regnr

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['regnr']

class ServiceTypes(models.Model):
    typ = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, blank=False)
    pris = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=False, blank=False)
    beskrivning = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.typ

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['typ']


class FordonsService(models.Model):
    regnr = models.ForeignKey(Fordonsregister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    typ = models.ForeignKey(ServiceTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_datum = models.DateTimeField()
    bokat_datum = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    kommentar = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-service_datum']
```

And here is the admin module:
The problem is with **class FordonsServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Count
from django.utils.html import format_html, urlencode
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpRequest
from .models import Fordonsregister, ServiceTypes, FordonsService

# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Fordonsregister)
class FordonsregisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['regnr', 'namn', 'tel', 'email', 'antal_bokningar', 'antal_offerter']
    search_fields = ['regnr__istartswith']

    def antal_bokningar(self, fordonsregister):
        url = (
        reverse('admin:main_fordonsservice_changelist')
        + '?'
        + urlencode({
            'fordonregister__regnr': str(fordonsregister.regnr)
        }))
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, fordonsregister.antal_bokningar)

    def antal_offerter(self, fordonsregister):
        url = (
        reverse('admin:kalkylator_standardoffert_changelist')
        + '?'
        + urlencode({
            'fordonsregister__regnr': str(fordonsregister.regnr)
        }))
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, fordonsregister.antal_offerter)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(antal_bokningar=Count("fordonsservice__service_datum"), 
                                     antal_offerter=Count("standardoffert__totalpris"))
        return queryset




@admin.register(FordonsService)
class FordonsServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['regnr', 'typ', 'service_datum', 'bokat_datum', 'regnr_id']
    search_fields = ['fordonsregister__regnr_id']


@admin.register(ServiceTypes)
class ServiceTypesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['typ', 'pris', 'antal_bokat']

    def antal_bokat(self, servicetypes):
        url = (
        reverse('admin:main_fordonsservice_changelist')
        + '?'
        + urlencode({
            'servicetypes__typ': str(servicetypes.typ)
        }))
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, servicetypes.antal_bokat)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(antal_bokat=Count("fordonsservice__service_datum"))
        return queryset
```

Comment: Which field are you exactly trying to access? Your questions don't state it clearly.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry :) This field: search_fields = ['fordonsregister__regnr_id'] basically its the primary key of the fordonsregister model which is the foreign key in the fordonservice model. I would like to be able to search the foreign key field for the regnr (primary key in other model)

Comment: Do you mean the model id here or the char field regnr_id? because there is nothing like `regnr_id` in your models.

Comment: i would like to search on the REGNR which is the primary key in the related model and the foreignkey in the model i want to add the Seach fields to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FordonsService` model has a foreign key `regnr` that points to the `Fordonsregister` model, which in turn has another `CharField` named `regnr` (maybe you can be a bit descriptive while naming attributes -- it will be helpful for you as well as others that will be working on the code).

Now, since you want to go from the foreign-key `regnr` and access any field on the `Fordonsregister` model, you do it via `model__attribute` syntax, like below:

```
@admin.register(FordonsService)
class FordonsServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['regnr', 'typ', 'service_datum', 'bokat_datum', 'regnr_id']
    search_fields = ['regnr__id', 'regnr__regnr']
```

This will add a search for both the `id` and the `regnr` attributes of the `Fordonsregister` model, which is linked to the `FordonsService` model.

Comment: Thanks now it works. Didn't know to access the key through the key with regnr__regnr . Many thanks! This issue was driving me nuts :-)

Regarding the "descriptive" comment, do you mean I should have different names in the models? These models are meant to focus at REGNR which means registration number in Swedish , its a widely accepted abbreviation for it.

Comment: The attribute name is fine in that case, though I'd make the foreign key name to be: `register` of `fordon_register` depending on your business logic. This would make it a little descriptive that it's a foreign key and not actually a registration number `regnr`.

Comment: Ok i see, very nice thanks. Im quite new to django (not python) so i appreciate your help and input, many thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped you @StevenMeesters, you can upvote the helpful answers on SO to indicate rest of the community that they're helpful.